# Model does not apply DataType.Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

Instead of using the object directly, on a simple Razor View I have a form using as it+s `model` a decorator object.

```
public class GlobalAccount
{
    public GlobalAccount()
    {
        this.TestService = new TestServiceModel();
    }

    public TestServiceModel TestService { get; set; }
}
```

beeing `TestServiceModel` represented as

```
public class TestServiceModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Endpoint (url of your service like http://mydomain/remote/)")]
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "System username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "System password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Note** the `Password` property decorated with `DataType.Password`

and in a `Partial Razor view` I have a call to that object

```
@model OnlineServices.Administration.Models.GlobalAccount
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TestService.Password, new { size = "30" })
```

problem is that, in the `html` I get `type="text"` instead of `text="password"`

You can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6gpQ.png) the entire flow:

[image]

> What am I **missing** here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `Html.Password`, or even better use `Html.EditorFor` which will read the `DataType.Password` and output a password type input for you.

The `Html.TextBoxFor` is just text based input, not as password based one.

Comment: dumb me ... so simple as yet so far away! I just overlook it... was always thinking about something wrong in the model and never saw with my own eyes the view :-/ **I NEED VACATIONS!** :o)

Comment: Consider using Html.PasswordFor instead (see @Skuld answer below)

Answer (score 14):

Further to Kieron's answer, in MVC3 it is actually NOT better to use Html.EditorFor for the Password inputs, as for some reason, if the server returns the page (say the username password combo is incorrect) then with EditorFor, the password is transmitted back to the page (and a view source the password is visible)

When using the Html.PasswordFor the password is not transmitted back to the client.

Comment: The server still returns the password in MVC 5. Another work-around is to go ahead and use `DataType.Password` and `Html.EditorFor`, but have the controller clear the password before returning the view (as in `viewModel.Password = null`).